# key based partitions in mysql for millions of rows

Tags: mysql, database, performance, partitioning, bigdata

My table has user id(primary key) and it's relation to other users, so table contains multiple rows for primary key. Right now I have 500k around users in system, so together these generated millions of rows in that table. 
Searching and other operation became so slow due to that, I checked about mysql partitioning, so want to understand that how I can use partitioning for this scenario so query will execute on that particular user id only (as in every query I used to pass user id in condition).

Comment: Before partitioning, have you played enough with indexes ? They might do the trick too

Comment: @PrabhatG I seen indexes but partitioning took my attention as if it works I will use it for other tables and DB's as well.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `SELECT` that seems to "need" partitioning.  I will _probably_ show you how to get as good or better performance _without_ partitioning.

Answer (score 1):

Before you look into partitions, have you considered adding indexes? Check your query planner to see if it does a full table scan.

Comment: how is this a solution, rather comment ?

Comment: @tomjen I checked about indexing but partitioning looks better. Right now it does full table scan that why I am more interested in partitioning.